# Conditional grouping in SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have a query with the `ORDER BY` clause, it works well but now I want that if the `field3` is equal to the string `good`, this string should not be grouped. I hope I explained.

```
String sql = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, COUNT (field3) 
FROM Table
WHERE field2 = '"+numero+"'
GROUP BY field3 ORDER BY field1 ASC ";
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please provide a sample of your data with the expected output.

Comment: @AleksG: It sounds like a CASE.  I'm not sure it's possible to have a conditional GROUPing, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, sounds like CASE, but I'd rather the OP provide sample data and expected output - much easier to understand :)

Comment: You probably need to run two separate queries, and UNION them together.

Comment: I don't believe the query as shown will work.  You'll need to group by ALL fields, not just field3.

Comment: well, this query selects the fields, count the field3 and groups them according to the field3. I wish if field3 is present in the data "good" it should not be grouped.

Comment: Create two separate queries.  The first will return your grouped records, the second will return your ungrouped records.  Combine them with a UNION.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, COUNT (field3)
FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 = '5' AND field3 <> 'good'
GROUP BY field3

UNION ALL

SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field3
FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 = '5' AND field3 = 'good'

ORDER BY field1
```

It uses a `union` statement to append the 'good' ones to the end.

Comment: With this solution I get `sintax Error near UNION`

Comment: @user2895164 I don't have a machine right now to test the query, so you're gonna have to fiddle with it a little bit. You still need to use a `union` for what you want though. I changed my answer a little bit, maybe the change fixes your problem, but once again, I can't really test it.

Comment: Fixed the syntax. (I still think the query doesn't make sense …)

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this if you want to exclude `filed3` from the result:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, COUNT (field3) 
FROM Table 
WHERE field2 = '"+numero+"'
GROUP BY field3 ORDER BY field1 ASC ) WHERE feild3 != 'good' ";
```

Good luck

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after.  He doesn't want to exclude records where field3 is 'good' - but rather not group those records.

Comment: Sorry to miss understanding. I edit my answer, I'am doing it  like that.